# How to understand "not just in arguments where it is alone" in find -exec command {} man page ;

Tags: shell, find, manpage

I don't fully understand this sentence "**not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find**" when I read the mannual page in [man find(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

I know the Shell will expand '{}' by the filename matched by **find**  wherever it appears in the arguments to the command.

**But** what does the find command of other versions process ''{}' ' with the interpretation  " just in arguments where it is alone" ?

I would appreciate it if you can give me an example to explain.

I'm not a English native speaker. So please forgive me if I misuse some words.

> **-exec command ;**
>
> Execute command; true if 0 status is returned. All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of ';' is encountered. The string '{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, **not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find**. Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a '') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell. See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the -exec option. The specified command is run once for each matched file. The command is executed in the starting directory. There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.

Comment: I recommend you using pipes and `xargs(1)` instead of using the obscure features of `find(1)`.

Comment: I recommend the exact opposite. Use `find -exec`, not `find | xargs`. `-exec` isn't an obscure feature. It's plenty common, and it's safe by default, unlike `xargs`. With `xargs` one should write `find -print0 | xargs -0`, but people usually aren't that careful. Most write `find | xargs`, which is short but barfs on all kinds of special characters.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'd say the problem is in using "all kinds of special characters" for filenames, not in `xargs(1)` per se.  I'd like to use this chance to recommend against using whitespace in filenames :).  My use of the word "obscure" referred to the unusual way that `find(1)` uses for its arguments, compared to other common tools.  So far, the only feature of `find` that I found useful (IMHO) is `-type`.